# Chatroom using flask

Tags: python, flask

I created simple chatroom using socket in python, Client part has  a thread that receives messages from socket and print them on terminal, but I want to show them on the html page.
I added incoming messages to list and show them on the html using jinja2 but with reloading page, they are appeared.
How can i add them to html page after they are received.

Receive thread:

```
while not self.__stop:
            try:
                ready, _, _ = select.select([self.soc,], [self.soc,], [], 5)
            except select.error:
                self.stop()
                return
            except ValueError:
                break
            if len(ready) > 0:
                incoming_data = b''
                try:
                    incoming_data = self.soc.recv(self.__BUFFER_SIZE) # TODO #3
                except ConnectionResetError:
                    log.error("Connection Reset Error")
                # Check if socket has been closed
                if incoming_data == b'':
                    log.info("Server disconnected.")
                    self.stop()
                else:
                    ip, port, msg = self.messageCallback(incoming_data)
                    if ip == "Server":
                        log.info("From Server: %s", msg)
                    else :
                        log.info("From <(%s, %s)> %s!", ip, port, msg)
```

flask code

```
@app.route('/<msg>/<other>', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post(msg = None, other = False):
    if other:
        print("From Others")
        data.append(msg)
    else:
        print("From yourself")
        text = request.form['text']
        send_msg.append({"msg":text, "ip":"127.0.0.1", "other":False})
        data.append({"msg":text, "ip":"127.0.0.1", "other":False})
    tmp = [data[i] for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1)]
    return render_template('GClient.html', data = tmp)
```

As i said, i want to reload page content on receiving new messages from socket.
How can i do that ???

Comment: you should use RabbitMQ messaging queue library.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: Thank you. But isn't there any straightforward solution using flask itself?

Comment: There is an alternate `WebSocket` solution to create a chat room.
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

Comment: This is so useful, thank you for your help.